# CSS counter does not increment for <h2>

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-counter

I am crafting a multicolumn, CSS-numbered, TOC like this:

```
| 1. TOC Level-1    | 2. TOC Level-1    |
| 1.1 TOC Level-2   | 2.1 TOC Level-2   |
| 1.2 TOC Level-2   | 2.2 TOC Level-2   |
| 1.3 TOC Level-2   | 3. TOC Level-1    |
                    | 3.1 TOC Level-2   |
```

Since CSS-columns are uncontrollable, wrapping is done with JS and a floating 'column' class.

Here's the example I follow:
http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/numbering-headingshtml.html

Here's the CSS I use:

```css
body {} .column {
  border: 2px dotted grey;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
.sub-nav-content {
  counter-reset: toc1;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: toc2;
}
h1:before {
  counter-increment: toc1;
  content: counter(toc1)". ";
}
h2:before {
  counter-increment: toc2;
  content: counter(toc1)"." counter(toc2)" ";
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-nav">
  <div class="sub-nav-content">
    <div class="column">
      <a class="menu-item"><h1>TOC entry level1</h1></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class=column>
      <a class="menu-item"><h1>TOC entry level1</h1></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h1>TOC entry level1</h1></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Somehow I can't get the Level-2 counter to increment.

Comment: No they wouldn't...CSS Counter are **highly** structure dependent. When you wrap the second 'column' you re-start the count.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. Whats the best way to achive what I need?

Comment: Something like this? http://output.jsbin.com/gakolo

Comment: Thank you @Mo for investigating

Comment: @MarcSmits: There is no need to change your wrap structure. Just change the inner structure and put the `h1`, `h2` under the `a`. That should do it.

Comment: Thank you @MoshFeu for investigating. Like Pauli_D has also stated: **Any form of wrapping an element, stops a CSS-counter to properly increment*. Selecting a element with CSS (including the number) requires it to be wrapped. The only way to achieve the above, is to hard-code the numbering, which means backend will have to generate it.

Comment: @MarcSmits: No, it doesn't. I guess you didn't read my comment. Your structure only need minor modification and CSS counter WILL work.

Comment: @Harry that could work, when only the `h1` `h2` would have a hover-state, neglecting the numbering `:before`.

Comment: No @MarcSmits You can still make the `:before` have the hover effect. I can post an answer if you wish.

Comment: I worked it out!!! Thanks @Harry. https://jsfiddle.net/ctrlspatie/141awch6/2/

Comment: @MarcSmits: But you see that the number is *continuing* under 2nd and 3rd `h1` right? It is not 1, 2, 3. It is starting from where it left off in the previous one. Is that what you needed? I don't think so. Anyway, I've also posted an answer with a working solution and also the reason why your original code didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can achieve this using CSS counters by tweaking your HTML and CSS just a bit. Firstly, put the `a` inside the `h1` or `h2` instead of the other way around. Secondly, increment the counter at the `h1` or `h2` level but use the `:before`  of the `a` to display the numbering. Thus the number will also have the `:hover` (as it is now part of the `a`).

**Demo:**

```css
body {} .column {
  border: 2px dotted grey;
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
.menu-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
.sub-nav-content {
  counter-reset: toc1;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: toc2;
}
h1 {
  counter-increment: toc1;
}
h1 a:before {
  content: counter(toc1)". ";
}
h2 {
  counter-increment: toc2;
}
h2 a:before {
  content: counter(toc1)"." counter(toc2)" ";
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-nav">
  <div class="sub-nav-content">
    <div class="column">
      <h1><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level1</a></h1>
      <h2><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level2</a></h2>
      <h2><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level2</a></h2>
      <h2><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level2</a></h2>
    </div>
    <div class=column>
      <h1><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level1</a></h1>
      <h2><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level2</a></h2>
      <h2><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level2</a></h2>
      <h1><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level1</a></h1>
      <h2><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level2</a></h2>
      <h2><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level2</a></h2>
      <h2><a class="menu-item">TOC entry level2</a></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Reason for Original Issue:**

The below was your structure (simplified). What you were doing is using `counter-reset` for `toc2` at the `h1` level but this `h1` is nested below the `a`.

```
<div class="sub-nav">
  <div class="sub-nav-content">
    <div class="column">
      <a class="menu-item"><h1>TOC entry level1</h1></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
      <a class="menu-item"><h2>TOC entry level2</h2></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As per [W3C Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#creating-counters), the scoping and inheritance of CSS counters works as follows:

- The current element ***gets*** all counters that its parent or a sibling has. (*counter inheritance*)
- It ***inherits*** the value of the counter from its previous sibling (or) the parent. (*value inheritance*)

Here, since the `toc1` counter was reset at the `.sub-nav-content` level, both the `.column` elements get the counter and all the `.menu-item` elements and their pseudo-element also get it (from their own parent). When the `counter-increment` is used on `h1:before`, it increments the value of the counter that was *got* from its parent, so all elements right up to `.sub-nav-content` know the existance of the counter and its current value. Thus each `h1` is able to increment it properly.

But the `toc2` is only reset at `h1` level. This means that none among `.sub-nav-content`, .`column` or `.menu-item` know about the existence of this counter. Only the `h1` and its children know it. So, when the `h2` elements are encountered, the UA sees if they already have that `toc2` counter or not and as they don't have it, a ***new*** `toc2` ***counter is created at each*** `h2` and they are incremented. Thus their value will always ever be only 1 and nothing else.